# C#: DateTime problems

Tags: c#, datetime

In a variable of DateTime typeI have this value = {30/07/2014 0:00:00}

I want only the date:

```
var aux = pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
```

with it I obtain 30/04/2014 correctly

but when I want to convert in MM/dd/yyyy using:

```
var aux2 = DateTime.ParseExact(aux, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

I have this error:

the string is represents one DateTime not admited in the GregorianCalendar

Why I have this error in aux2?

Comment: Try DateTime.TryParse, that will handle MM/dd/yyyy (assuming your culture is correct)

Comment: mm, you could DateTime xy = DateTime.Parse(whatever_string); and then get just the date xy.Date

Comment: I am pretty sure that your string variable aux doesn't contain the string that you expect.

Comment: dont be so sure, I have the result as I said CORRECTLY in string format, take a look again the question

Comment: 30 in "30/07/2014" is not valid number of month (December is the last and it is twelfth), so "MM/dd/yyyy" is not correct parsing pattern for it. Use "dd/MM/yyyy" instead or make sure that you use correct strings - there is some discrepancy in your question : "with it({30/07/2014 0:00:00}???) I obtain 04/30/2014".

Comment: Are you trying to get a `DateTime` variable with the date in, or a `string` with the date in?

Comment: How about `pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.Date`?

Comment: true Eugene Podskal, what you say is true, Imistook to write in question really is a string with 30/04/2014 and then I want to convert to MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your locale setting. Calling `ToString()` without parameters on a date value produces a string with the pattern day,month,year arranged differently between locales. (And I suppose that you get a string arranged with Day,Separator, Month, Separator, Year).
Passing that string to `DateTime.ParseExact` with a specific pattern (MM/dd/yyyy) requires the string to be in the exact pattern required Month, Day, Year for your example.

You could force the invariant culture in your conversion with

```
 var aux = pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(' ')[0];
```

this produces a string with the pattern required by the subsequent ParseExact mask

However it is not clear why you need these conversions. A date is not a string and you simply keep it as a date and use the conversion only when you need to represent it somewhere (display, print etc...)

```
 Console.WriteLine("Date is:" + pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Surely it would be better to match an explicit format string with another explicit format string, rather than a `CultureInfo` that happens to match the format string after applying a `Split` to the result? Or even to ask why OP is converting a `DateTime` to a `string` and immediately back again?

Comment: Well, both of your points are correct. The OP is not clear about what causes this transformation from date to string and then back to date. If

Answer (score -1):

When you call below :
`var aux = pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.ToString().Split(' ')[0];`

This gives you code "07-30-2014" and not "07/30/2014" and that's generate the error while conversion. So to get "07/30/2014", you have to write

```
var aux = pedido.ord_cus_deliv_date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(' ')[0];
```

Below is overall code for you:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.Parse("30/07/2014 0:00:00"); //your date time value

var aux = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(' ')[0];

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(aux, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var aux2 = dt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split(' ')[0]);
```

I hope this will help you

Regards,
Sandeep